# How to create your own controller in Magento

Tags: magento

I am new to mangento. I have the knowledge on MVC architecture and codeigniter framework. Now I am working on magento. I tried with some of the tutorials that how to create the our own controller. But not getting the proper response.

So please share me some of the links through which I can learn magento. As i learnt the codeigniter with ellislab, there has no such tutorials found for me to learn magento.

Please share if anybody have the video links, through which I can learn magento.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use module  creator or check on web.
here is one of the link I can suggest for Magento:-
https://mementia.com/creating-custom-magento-module